# Doctrine query_cache auto expire

Tags: symfony, redis, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony 3.4 + doctrine + redis by using the composer bundle [sncRedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

In my config.yml I enabled **doctrine query cache**:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            auto_mapping: false
            metadata_cache_driver: redis
            query_cache_driver: redis
            result_cache_driver: redis # !!!

snc_redis:
clients:

    doctrine:
        type: predis
        alias: doctrine_redis
        dsn: "%redis_dsn_doctrine%"
        logging: false
        options:
            connection_persistent: true

doctrine:
    query_cache: #!!!!!!!!
      #it caches the translation from Doctrine's DQL into SQL.
        client: doctrine_redis
        namespace: shop_doctrine_query  
        entity_manager: [default, legacy]
```

The keys set by doctrine for it's result_cache never expire:
[image]

How can I call automatically `\Doctrine\ORM\Query::setQueryCacheLifetime` or make that cache expire. (Note I don't have access to set redis eviction policies on this server).

Comment: Could you provide us your `config/packages/*/cache.yaml` files and the return of `symfony console cache:pool:list`

Answer (score 1):

I think that Doctrine query cache lifetime aren't configured in the doctrine package nor in the redis package, but in the framework package, where you set your pool of cache.

You should have a look on [this issue](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/issues/554) where a user is asking how to configure RedisCluster with Doctrine Cache. B-Galati answers with a configuration example where it defines lifetime for doctrine result cache.

Could you try something like:

```yaml
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            cache.doctrine.orm.default.query: ## I'm not sure of this name
                adapter: cache.app
                default_lifetime: 25200 # 1 week
```

Or

```yaml
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.query_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
                default_lifetime: 25200 # 1 week
```

The `symfony console cache:pool:list` command could help you to identify your pools and the `symfony console cache:pool:prune` could help you to see if out of date queries are well deleted.

Comment: does this work with symfony 3.4? it just ignores it